# How do I use the Bellard Formula to extract a specific digit of pi?

Tags: sequences-and-series, pi, decimal-expansion

I know you can easily calculate digits of $\pi$ using summation by using the Bellard formula.

$$
\pi ={\frac {1}{2^{6}}}\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }{\frac {(-1)^{n}}{2^{10n}}}\,\left(-{\frac {2^{5}}{4n+1}}\right.{}-{\frac {1}{4n+3}}+{\frac {2^{8}}{10n+1}}-{\frac {2^{6}}{10n+3}}\left.{}-{\frac {2^{2}}{10n+5}}-{\frac {2^{2}}{10n+7}}+{\frac {1}{10n+9}}\right)
$$

However, you still need to use summation for this. What I am wondering is: how can I extract a specific digit of $\pi$ using the Bellard Formula?

Comment: you bound the error term with respect to the $n$'th partial sum and take $n$ large enough so that you can be certain of the first $k$ digits

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by this? Maybe provide some mathematical equation?

Comment: Note that such formulas do not allow to calculate the $n$ th digit immediately. The only advantage is that we do not need all previous digits and can therefore calculate the result much faster. But this does not allow us to compute , lets say , the $10^{10^{100}}$ th digit in a reasonable amount of time. I am moreover only aware from formulas for $\pi$ and base $2$.